# Get a list of post titles and links from yootheme master theme

Tags: categories

Hi I am using the yootheme master collection and I wish to get a list of 10 permalinks from this custom post catagory but at the moment I can only get 1 to show. How do I do this properly?

Cheers

```
<div id="rec-p" style="width:80%; height:100%; border:2px dotted red; float:left; ">


<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

    <?php if (is_category()) : ?>
        <?php /* <h1 class="page-title">Archive for the &#8216;<?php single_cat_title(); ?>&#8217; Category</h1> */ ?>
    <?php elseif (is_tag()) : ?>
        <h1 class="page-title"><?php printf(__('Posts Tagged %s', 'warp'), '&#8216;'.single_tag_title('', false).'&#8217;'); ?></h1>
    <?php elseif (is_day()) : ?>
        <h1 class="page-title"><?php printf(__('Archive for %s', 'warp'), get_the_date()); ?></h1>
    <?php elseif (is_month()) : ?>
        <h1 class="page-title"><?php printf(__('Archive for %s', 'warp'), get_the_date('F, Y')); ?></h1>
    <?php elseif (is_year()) : ?>
        <h1 class="page-title"><?php printf(__('Archive for %s', 'warp'), get_the_date('Y')); ?></h1>
    <?php elseif (is_author()) : ?>
        <h1 class="page-title"><?php _e('Author Archive', 'warp'); ?></h1>
    <?php elseif (isset($_GET['paged']) && !empty($_GET['paged'])) : ?>
        <h1 class="page-title"><?php _e('Blog Archives', 'warp'); ?></h1>
    <?php endif; ?>


    <?php $currentid = get_the_id(); ?>

    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($currentid); ?></a></h2>




<?php else : ?>

    <?php if (is_category()) : ?>
        <h1 class="page-title"><?php printf(__("Sorry, but there aren't any posts in the %s category yet.", "warp"), single_cat_title('', false)); ?></h1>
    <?php elseif (is_date()) : ?>
        <h1 class="page-title"><?php _e("Sorry, but there aren't any posts with this date.", "warp"); ?></h1>
    <?php elseif (is_author()) : ?>
        <?php $userdata = get_userdatabylogin(get_query_var('author_name')); ?>
        <h1 class="page-title"><?php printf(__("Sorry, but there aren't any posts by %s yet.", "warp"), $userdata->display_name); ?></h1>
    <?php else : ?>
        <h1 class="page-title"><?php _e("No posts found.", "warp"); ?></h1>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php get_search_form(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
 <?wp_reset_query();
        ?>
```

Comment: Your loop does not use your `$my_query` and also is incomplete. See example: [WP_Query Usage](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Usage).

Comment: Hi sorry $my_query was not supposed to be there I have changed it now.  Any advice? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've mentioned in the comment to the question, your loop is incomplete. You need `while` loop to iterate through posts and `the_post()` function to get those posts one by one:

```
<?php
// if there are posts
if ( have_posts() ) :
    // iterate through all posts
    while ( have_posts() ) :
        // get post data
        the_post();
        // your post here 
    endwhile;
else:
    // if no posts;
endif; ?>
```

See Codex:

- [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)
- [The Loop in
  Action](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop_in_Action)
- [Function Reference/the_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post)